# What is the Angular JS equivalent of this Curl command?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, curl

curl -d @datavalueset.xml "https://apps.dhis2.org/demo/api/dataValueSets" -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -u admin:district -v

Answer (score 1):

Somethink like this. Keep in mind that you must provide the xml as string.

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://admin:district@apps.dhis2.org/demo/api/dataValueSets',
    data: '<content/>', // put here your XML
    headers: { "Content-Type": 'application/xml' }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. But I get this error when I run the code. XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://apps.dhis2.org/demo/api/dataValueSets. The request was redirected to 'https://apps.dhis2.org/demo/dhis-web-commons/security/login.action;jsessionid=91C653D8C32841195559F96A82615A82', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.